# Is Placing a form to video is a best practice or not

Tags: video

I have a product site, in which i have a page called Demo. To view this demo, i have placed a form to be filled so that i can contact them. The form contains basic questions such as Email ID, Name, Phone Number.

So, customers can view the video only after filling the form.

Is it a good practice to place a form or not.

Comment: If I have to give my details just to see a video I'll find another website.

Answer (score 1):

You could make some sort of login system where users have to register, and only members can see the videos.

But you'll be effectively required to have a privacy policy of how you are going to use your visitors' information.

But personally, if I were you, I'd just provide the videos out publicly until bandwidth costs are considerable.

Answer (score 1):

I would see that as an obstacle.  You want to hook them first with the video and then place a call to action that has them fill out the form for more information.